# HeartBeat Vibration

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-vibrate

I want to vibrate device like heart-beat same as provided by system in
Settings->Sound & Haptics->Ring Tone->Vibration->Heatbeat.

I have tried this but it only vibrate once. Also tried it in loop as well as after some delay but not solve my problem.

```
func vibrate() {
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
}
```

Comment: Do you succeeded to generate Heartbeat vibration just like the iPhone's Heartbeat vibration?

Comment: No. I used the above mentioned vibration effect instead.